# Laravel passport oauth/tokens GET API not working

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I just installed Passport and added `Passport::routes()` to my serviceprovider. It gave me these routes `/oauth/token POST`, `/oauth/tokens GET`, `/oauth/token/{Token_id} DELETE`. 
I am using Password Grant Tokens for authentication(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#password-grant-tokens)

I ran the POST request to make a new token and it created the token just fine. But when I try to run the GET to see all the token, it returns an empty array. I have around 10 tokens already generated in my DB.

Shouldn't I be getting a list of all the oauth tokens that's stored in the database?
If not, Is there a way to index all the tokens for admin use?

Answer (score 1):

The `GET /oauth/tokens` route returns all tokens for the currently authenticated user only, not all users.

To get all tokens, with their associated users, you can use the following.

```php
\Laravel\Passport\Token::with('user')->get()
```

Comment: But this only gives me what's in the database. I want the actual access_token returned by that create endpoint, which is way longer than what's stored in DB

Comment: May I ask why? What's in the database is what controls access, what you are getting back from the `POST /oauth/token` endpoint is a Javascript web token, essentially just a cryptographic wrapper around the actual token with some additional data for access control. Revoking the token in the `tokens` table is all you need to do to revoke the full JWT. The JWT is also generated dynamically at the the time of the request, it's not stored because it doesn't need to be. It'd be like storing the TLS encoded request fora form instead of the actual form data